# Dragover: Can't move to left and top

Tags: javascript

I have an element which I would like to move with the mouse.

```js
var troll = document.getElementById('troll');

troll.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.target.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  e.target.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
}, false);
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="troll">
  <img src="http://images.mmorpg.com/features/7909/images/Troll.png" alt="Troll">
</div>
```

From left to right and from top to bottom it works OK. Not perfect, since the very first move takes a whole space and it doesn't look smooth. But the main problem is that I can't move from right to left or from bottom to top.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanna use drag not dragover, and some logic to know where you're going up or down or left or top.

```js
var troll = document.getElementById('troll');

var X,Y = 0;

troll.addEventListener('drag', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
 
  if (e.clientX > X) 
  {
    e.target.style.left = X + 'px'; 
  }
  else if (e.clientX < X) 
  {
    e.target.style.left = X-- + 'px'; 
  }
 

  if (e.clientY > Y) 
  {
    e.target.style.top = Y + 'px'; 
  }
  else if (e.clientY < Y) 
  {
    e.target.style.top = Y-- + 'px'; 
  }


  
  X = e.clientX;
  Y = e.clientY;
  
 
}, false);
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="troll">
  <img src="http://images.mmorpg.com/features/7909/images/Troll.png" alt="Troll">
</div>
```